# how to get the same style for 2 tables?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to get the same style on each row. In the 1st row (containing 'het regent vandaag') I have the following rule:

```
.attachments-table td {
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The 2ndrow contains a table with 2 rows has this set too but some other styling makes the rows heigher and the odd/even style is missing. How can I adjust this to make the style for the nested table the same as the style in the 1st row so height and background color (even/oneven)?

I created a plunkr to clarify this a bit more:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SmHIWILedmdcLCsFCR9X?p=preview

Comment: Please post the minimal amount of code required to answer this question. Links should be used to supplement your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean but setting the table class to the same value will apply the same css styling to both tables

```
<table class = "value">
```

You will need to do the same for the td tags

Answer (score 0):

The inside `tr` elements also need the `highlight` class. See here, I've copied the `class="table-row clickable highlight"` to them (but highlight only is fine): http://plnkr.co/edit/nadWysWfOliXABdjUCBa?p=preview